# How can I set a query filter to a Datalist in jPlaton platform which is of type Record Descriptor?

Tags: filter, datalist

In the jPlaton platform, I have a lookup Datalist which is defined as a record descriptor.
I want the Datalist's values to be filtered each time another field in my form changes value.

So say e.g. I have a Datalist with Contacts. What I want is, each time I select an Account in another
Datalist in my form, the Contacts' Datalist values will be filtered so only the contacts belonging to
the selected Account will be displayed, not all contacts.

Is there a way to accomplish this with PlatonScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the user selects something in a DataList the value is passed to the variable - field  on which it is attached, triggering the "on_set" event. So all you have to do is write a procedure, bind it with the on_set event and use the function setDataSet to overwrite the DataSet created automatically from the platform.

example

```
*Procedure PROPERTIES*

<s_getAccounttId
        action_type="s_testRec.on_set"
></s_getAccounttId>

*Procedure SOURCES*

<s_getAccounttId>
        <![CDATA[START:s_getAccounttId
        IF (#SOURCE#=="TABLENAME.ACCOUNT_ID")
        {
            IF (#s_testRec.ACCOUNT_ID# != 0)
            {
                ACTION s_accountContactsSet EXECUTE
                setDataSet s_testRec.CONTACT_ID s_accountContactsSet
                *do something*
            }
            ELSE
            {
                *do something else*
            }

        }
        return 1 ]]>
</s_getAccounttId>
```

where

- s_getAccoutId is the procedure triggered
- TABLENAME.ACCOUNT_ID is a field whose value will cause the event triggering
- s_testRec.CONTACT_ID is the record descriptor field with the automatically bind DataList
- s_accountContactsSet is the new DataList which will be bind s_testRec.CONTACT_ID